# Two Primary keys that are the same, but in two different tables

Tags: sql

I just have a quick question for ya's about primary keys in SQL. I have a primary key in one table (Patient) and another table (Facility) with a different primary key. What I want to do is connect them so I have my primary key from Patient and have that exact primary key (with data) in my Facility table. How do I go about doing this? Thanks for any help in advance, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: show us some query that you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a JOIN. See [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for some details.

Comment: Did u mean this?
Patient.id = Facility.id

Comment: ALTER TABLE Facility
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PatientID)
REFERENCES Patient (PatientID)

Comment: Okay, will look at the article now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting kind of relation. But you can do it inserting the same id to both tables:

```
INSERT INTO Parient(ID, NAME)      VALUES (5, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO Facility(ID, LOCATION) VALUES (5, 'San Francisco');
```

You can alos use a sequence for the first insert and then use generated new id for the second insert (current value).

*Note*: I do not recommend this practice of ID synchronization. The better way to go is to let your database assign unique IDs for us (using sequence of auto-increment) and then define foreign key constraint adding `FACILITY_ID` to the Patient table or `PATIENT_ID` to the Facility table implementing one-to-one relationship.

Comment: What I am trying to do is, say I have PatientID 420 in the Patient table, I want to be able to have that exact same PatientID of 420 in my Facility table. So basically, I want to assign a patient(patient table) to a location (facility table).

Comment: You can do it when you select data like this: `SELECT p.name, f.location FROM parient p, facility f WHERE p.id=f.id`.

Comment: Ya, but my primary key in my facility table is FacilityID, I don't even have PatientID (Primary key in Patient table) in the Facility table like I do the Patient table

Comment: Oh, I understand. Each table must have an ID. This is essential for the data integrity! If you want further help, please add table specifications to your question. Adding more details is also appreciated.

Comment: My tables specifications are as follows: Patient table (PatientID, and a bunch of other columns) and I have another table Facility with columns FacilityID, and Location. I want to assign a PatientID from the Patient table (a PatientID that already exists in the Patient table, that is) to a Location in the Facility table

Answer (score 1):

Add an other table ( eg hospitalization ) that contains both keys:

```
create table hospitalization ( 
  patient_id int not null,  
  facility_id int not null, 
  date_start date not null,
  date_end date
);
```

this is a standard many to many relation with properties and means that a patient could be hospitalized many times and each facility could have many patients.